# Javascript: Image change

Tags: javascript

Very simple thing which I am not able to do.
I have two images viz. `try.jpg` and `menuBack.jpg`.
Initially, I put `try.jpg` as image source but as soon as the page loads I want to change it to the other image.

HTML:

```
<img id="imgSlider" width="284px" height="284px" src="try.jpg"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
    var imageSrc = document.getElementById("imgSlider").src;
    imageSrc == "menuBack.jpg";
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is the 'wrong way around'.  So you need to assign `menuBack.jpg` to `document.getElementById("imgSlider").src;`

Also you were using double `==` which is a logical operator for "is something equal to something else?".

Finally, add the brackets after `initAll()`.

```
window.onload = initAll();


function initAll(){
    document.getElementById("imgSlider").src = "menuBack.jpg";

}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaUqb/) of it working (obviously a fake image location, but if you inspect the element with your browser dev tools then you can see it has changed).

Comment: Ok that worked. BUt stilll didnt get what was wrong with the code above. I shoudl ahve used = instead of ==. thats fine. But it still didnt. As soon as i copy pasted the jsFiddle code, it worked

Comment: Change it to my single line of code. This line is grabbing the element imgSlider and assigning `menuBack.jpg` to it's `src` property. Before you were grabbing this property, saving it to another variable and then changing that variable later.  This doesn't change the original `src` property, it just changes the variable.

Comment: Also, add the `()` to `initAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you'll want to do is something like this:

```
document.getElementById("imgSlider").src = "menuBack.jpg";
```

What you are looking to do is actually an assignment statement - for that you use only one `=-` equals character. You use two `==` equals characters to do conditional expressions (`if..then..else`).